# Admob ads displaying but click through doesn't work

Tags: android, admob

I'm using the GoogleMobileAdsSdkAndroid.zip (Version 6.4.1), with android-13 specified as the target in project.properties in Eclipse.

When I was developing and testing the app, I was using adMob in test mode. The ads loaded, displayed and refreshed ok.  However, when I clicked on an ad, it didn't click through. A window opens very very briefly but immediately closes and my app resumes again (it looks like the onResume method is called from a brief inspection).

I thought that this was just due to it being in test mode, so I pushed my app out to Google Play anyway with testing turned off.

However, testing it on a friend's phone, it does exactly the same thing.

Any ideas gratefully received?

Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas please? I'm still struggling with this. I've even got a stackoverflow tumbleweed badge now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cracked it! The AdMob Activity and the main activity for my app have to run in the same process. I had specified a particular process in the main activity for my app in the AndroidManifest.xml, but hadn't specified the same process in the AdMob activity. As soon as I did that, all is working.
.

Comment: I solved it by adding this in AndroidManifest.xml :
 <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:multiprocess="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the following code from onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded method and problem solved!

```
if (unifiedNativeAd!= null) {
   unifiedNativeAd.destroy();
  }
```